# NodeJS request not returned

Tags: node.js, express

[Swagger Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6NGy.png)

This is the source code

API.js

```
router.post('/curriculum2_section/', (req,res)=> {
    curriculum2_section.CREATE(req.body.curr2_section,req.body.curr2_id,req.body.curr2_section_student_amount)
})
```

curriculum2_section.js

```
  module.exports.CREATE =  function CREATE(curr2_section,curr2_id,curr2_section_student_amount) {
var sqlString = `INSERT INTO curriculum2_section(curr2_id,curr2_section,curr2_section_student_amount)VALUES('${curr2_id}',${curr2_section},${curr2_section_student_amount})` 
pool.getConnection((err, conn) => {
    if(err) throw err 
    pool.query(sqlString, function (err, rows) {
        console.log('Query String:\n '+this.sql);
        if(err) throw err 
        console.log('Data Insert: '+curr2_section+','+curr2_id+','+curr2_section_student_amount)
        conn.release();
    })
})
}
```

I've tried using the callback but it doesn't work. I think it because I don't understand how to use it

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the data you want to output to a method on `res` in order to get output from Express.

Given what you have here, your best bet might be to add a callback as the last parameter of `curriculum2_section.CREATE` and use that callback to pass data to `res`.

https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res

```js
router.post('/curriculum2_section/', (req,res)=> {
  curriculum2_section.CREATE(req.body.curr2_section,req.body.curr2_id,req.body.curr2_section_student_amount, (err, data) => {
    res.send(data);
 });
});
```

```js
module.exports.CREATE =  function CREATE(curr2_section,curr2_id,curr2_section_student_amount, cb) {
var sqlString = `INSERT INTO curriculum2_section(curr2_id,curr2_section,curr2_section_student_amount)VALUES('${curr2_id}',${curr2_section},${curr2_section_student_amount})` 
pool.getConnection((err, conn) => {
    if(err) throw err 
    pool.query(sqlString, function (err, rows) {
        console.log('Query String:\n '+this.sql);
        if(err) throw err 
        console.log('Data Insert: '+curr2_section+','+curr2_id+','+curr2_section_student_amount)
        conn.release();
        cb(null, 'Data Insert: '+curr2_section+','+curr2_id+','+curr2_section_student_amount);
    })
})
}
```